# JSoup XPath/Selector query not working

Tags: java, jsoup, xsoup

I am trying to extract the GitHub link from this page

```
https://plugins.jenkins.io/hugo
```

val doc = JSoup.parse("https://plugins.jenkins.io/hugo")

XPath from Chrome

```
//*[@id="grid-box"]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a
```

Selector from Chrome

```
#grid-box > div > section > div.dialog > div.content > div > div > div.col-md-9.main > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > a
```

JSoup Query

```
#grid-box > div > section > div:eq(2) > div:eq(2) > div > div > div:eq(1) > div > div > div:eq(1) > div:eq(2) > a
```

Code Snippet

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import us.codecraft.xsoup.Xsoup;

val doc = Jsoup.parse("https://plugins.jenkins.io/hugo")
Xsoup.compile("""//*[@id="grid-box"]/div/section/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/a""").evaluate(doc).list
```

tried with XPath, Selector as well and not able to extract value

I need the github link on this page

```
<a href="https://github.com/jenkinsci/hugo-plugin">GitHub →</a>
```

Can anyone please point me to the correct API if possible?

Comment: Did you try with the selector from Chrome?

Comment: Yes , I actually copied it from Chrome

Comment: Why are you using `Jsoup.parse(link)` and not `Jsoup.connect(link).get()`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("https://plugins.jenkins.io/hugo");    
Elements aTags = doc.select("a[data-reactid=\"30\"]");
```

It should parse this: `<a href="https://github.com/jenkinsci/hugo-plugin" data-reactid="30">GitHub →</a>`

Then from `aTags` you can do `aTags.attr("href")`, that should give you the URL. That's the idea.

If you can't see the `data-reactid` then you could do `divs = doc.select("div[col-md-4]")` then from `divs`, you get the `a` tag and `href` attribute. The idea is to find something unique from the HTML tags and attributes and target it in order to get the URL.

Comment: I don't have that option as the element is


       `<a href="https://github.com/jenkinsci/hugo-plugin">GitHub →</a>`

Comment: Why don't you have that option? If I inspect the element or view source, I can see `data-reactid` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what your looking for.

```
Elements githubLinks = doc.getElementsByAttributeValueStarting("href", "https://github.com/");
for(Element link : githubLinks) {
    System.out.println(link.attr("href"));
}
```